# How to build a multiple language bootstrapper setup.exe with WIX 3.7

Tags: msbuild, wix, installation, bootstrapper, wix3.7

I have a setup project build with WIX 3.7 which includes 3 languages (English, French and German). Build output is setup_en-us.msi, setup_fr-fr.msi and setup_de-de.msi. For every MSI a bootstrapper (for .NET 4.5) setup.exe is generated with following line in the .wixproj:

```
<GenerateBootstrapper ApplicationName="$(ProductName)" BootstrapperItems="@(BootstrapperFile)" ComponentsLocation="HomeSite" CopyComponents="True" OutputPath="$(TargetDir)%(CultureGroup.OutputFolder)" Culture="%(CultureGroup.Identity)" FallbackCulture="en-us" Path="$(BootstrapperPath)" />
```

Now I've managed to include all three language in one MSI setup.msi.

My problem is that you can only set one language while generating the bootstrapper setup.exe but I would prefer that the setup.exe includes all 3 languages, too.

Is there a possibility to create such a setup.exe?